# Where to find the schema for XMPP presence

Tags: xsd, xmpp

Is there an XMPP XSD or schema file defined somewhere for all available standard options for the presence stanza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in [RFC 6120, Appendix A](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#schemas-client).

The normative definition of presence stanzas however is in RFC 6121, which relates to using XMPP for IM in particular. See [RFC 6121 section 4.7](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-syntax).